# How to apply a function to certain columns while keeping the entire data frame?

Tags: r, apply, lapply

I am trying to assign NA to certain columns in a data frame when they equal 33.

```
df$A[df$A == 33] <- NA
df$B[df$B == 33] <- NA
df$C[df$C == 33] <- NA
```

...and so on.

I ran below codes

```
as.data.frame(apply(df[,c('A','B','C','D',...etc)], MARGIN=2, function(x) {ifelse(x==33, NA, x)}))
```

but this leaves me a data frame consists of only those specified columns. (I try to avoid cbind because it gets complicated when I actually need to do multiple cbind/rbind/merge at any step) 
Is there a simpler way of doing it?

Comment: `dplyr::mutate_at` is designed for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tidyverse version is something like

```
df = df %>% dplyr::mutate_at(c('A', 'B', 'C'), tidyr::na_if, 33)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option, specify the columns of interest in a vector ('nm1') and assign the subset of columns where that subset is equal to 33 with `NA`

```
nm1 <- c("A", "B", "C")
df[nm1][df[nm1]==33] <- NA
```

Or with `is.na`

```
is.na(df[nm1]) <- df[nm1] == 33
```

Comment: The question said *"certain columns"*, which suggests there are columns to be avoided. Perhaps `df[ind] <- lapply(df[ind], ...)`?